# Creating Polygon from a Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector, polygonize, smoothing

I have a Raster representing climate data. I converted the raster to vector using the tool raster to vector (Arc Map) and i got something like below:
[image: CLIMATE DATA]

Can somebody help me out by guiding me in actual smoothing the edges to make it look like a polygon. Im using Arc Map 10.2 and also except answers for QGIS and ILWIS Software.

Comment: I think you need to classify it first so that adjacent cells have same (not similar) values - it looks too complex. On the Raster to Polygon tool there's a tick box for simplify which will make polygons less boxy but will also make individual pixels triangles instead of squares.

Comment: @ Michael, i am using the simplify polygon tool with bend simplify as the simplification algorithm, what do i put as the simplification tolerance, i tried adding values like 1000 square meters but it keep on saying enter simplification tolerance. Your assistance please.

Comment: don't try to clean the vectors, it will only lead to tears. Smooth/Classify/mean the raster and convert that to polygons. Try something like Focal Statistics with Majority if you have already classified it and then convert to polygons with simplify polygons checked.

Comment: Did you read "a tick box " in @MichaelMiles-Stimson suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the toool used, you need to resample your raster to have more pixels (therefore having a smaller pixels size) before vectorisation. Considering you have already classified your data as suggested in the comments, the resampling will give you visualy smoother angles at the same scale as displayed.

You can also merge classes to get more homogeneous areas, therefore having less smaller micro-areas.